# Scrapy uses wrong encoding, adds extra html tags to JSON from webpage

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping, scrapy

So I want to use Scrapy to get
[Puerto Rico board game data](https://en.boardgamearena.com/table/table/tableinfos.html?id=27238963)

The data looks like the following

```
  { "data": {
    ...
    "label":"<div class=\"iblock\">\u262f &ge; 75%<\/div>"
    ...
   }
```

However, the response.text object in Scrapy uses a different encoding and adds some extra html tags:

```
<html><head></head><body>
 {"data": { 
   ... 
 "label": "<div class="\&quot;iblock\&quot;">\u262f ≥ 75%&lt;\/div&gt;"
  ...
  }
</div></body></html>
```

As a result, when I try to parse the json into a python object:

```
responseJSON = json.loads(response.xpath("/html/body/text").extract_first())
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: end is out of bounds
```

How can I get Scrapy to return a correcly encoded response with no extra html tags?

Comment: show how do you get this string. Maybe problem is in different place. Do you use selenium or similar tool ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
json.loads(response.text)
```

this is json response, no need to use xpath

Tested in scrapy shell

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but it gives me ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded").

Comment: Figured it out.  One of my middlewares was messing it up.  Now your answer works